# Editar la HORA CORRECTA en archivo de email .php

Tags: php

Tengo un asunto con mi servidor, y es que no respeta la hora de envío de los correos PHP, y cualquier correo enviado de la página web (ejemplo) a las 20:00 hs, es mostrado en el cuerpo del mensaje como enviado a las 18:00 hs, por cuanto pregunto si hay posibilidad de **editar la línea de time** (en mi archivo PHP de correo) **para sumar las 2 horas** que corresponden.

Mi actual linea PHP es la siguiente:

**NOTA:** La hora correcta para mi caso es **MADRID**

---

```
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "Fecha: " . date('d/m/Y H:i', time());
```

---

Gracias de antemano !.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega esto en las primeras líneas de tu php:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
```

[Aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) la referencia de uso de date_default_timezone_set.

Mira [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php) el listado de zonas permitidas, solo elige la región:

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!